# Spring HelloWorld Program not giving output

Tags: spring, maven, pom.xml

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("HelloWorldBean.xml");
HelloWorld h1 = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("b1");
h1.getMsg(); 
h1.getName();
```

Here all things are good, maven dependencies are added , but this `getMsg`  or `getName` method not giving any output.

If I write

```
System.out.println(h1.getMsg() + h1.getName()  );
```

It will give value of msg and name variable.

What is wrong in this can anybody help?

Comment: can you post your HelloWorldBean.xml

Comment: Nothing looks wrong to me. You seem to confuse "returning a String from a method" and "printing a String". You shouldn't be using Spring yet if you don't understand this difference. That would be like flying a Boeing 747 when you haven't learnt to walk and speak.

Answer (score 1):

In pojo , **getMsg** should have `System.out.println(msg);` then it will print, otherwise you have to manually put **getMsg** method to **sysout* as you shown.